# What is the problem here? I was trying to increment value but it's giving output as 0

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Been at this for hours, I'm new to LISP and could not figure out what is wrong with this. I'm trying to solve a matrix problem using backtracking. Can someone help?

```
(defvar m 3)
(defvar n 4)
(defvar M-DASH (make-array (list m n)
    :initial-contents '((1 0 1 0) (0 1 1 0) (1 0 1 1))))
(defvar selected (make-array n))
(defvar set-count 0)
(defun cand-set-count (M-DASH set-count selected curr)
  (if (>= curr m)
    (progn
      (incf set-count)
      (return-from cand-set-count 0)
    ))
  (loop for i from 0 to (- n 1)
    do (if (and (equal (aref M-DASH curr i) 1) (null (aref selected i)))
      (progn 
          (setf (aref selected i) 1)
          (cand-set-count M-DASH set-count selected (+ curr 1))
          (setf (aref selected i) nil)
      ))))
(cand-set-count M-DASH set-count selected 0)
(format t "~A" set-count)
```

Comment: The error says that you have an unmatched closing parenthesis `)` on line 25

Comment: I wrote this article for setting up common lisp with emacs https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-set-up-common-lisp-ide-in-2021-5be70d88975b - you should use `roswell` and inside it emacs with slime. Follow the instructions. `slime` will indent your code properly. And that helps a lot! At the end, lisp programmers need only put their attention on the proper indentation in e.g. slime - and they don't need to count parantheses any more!

Comment: By the way, if one mentioned Emacs, there is an interactive function to find mismatched parenthesis with ‘Alt+X’ and then type the command ‘check-paren’. It should jump to the location where the mismatch is detected. Pretty handy!

Comment: What exactly - in human words - you want to achieve with the `cand-set-count` function? In simple words? - I have the feeling it is something not so difficult - something which one would express differently, once one knows what it is the aim ...

Answer (score 5):

Before answering the actual question, a few notes on style and general remarks:

- Special variables (i.e. introduced by `defvar` or `defparameter`) are usually named with a name starting and ending with * (for example, `(defvar *m* 4)`
- Unless you did some very weird modifications, the reader won't be case sensitive. This means that `M-DASH` and `m-dash` are *the same symbol*. For this reason, we tend not to use any form of capitalization, as it might induce some mistakes (*e.g.* believing that two symbols are different while they are in fact identical ...).
- If you use a `if` but only care about the `then` or the `else` part, use `when/unless` instead. It makes intent clearer, and also comes with what is known as an "implicit progn":

  (if some-test
  (progn
  (do-smtg)
  (do-smtg-else)))

  is identical to

  (when some-test
  (do-smtg)
  (do-smtg-else))
- If you are only looping from 0 to some number, and not doing very complex things (or, if you are a beginner, and don't want to deal with the specific syntax rules of the `loop` macro ...), use `dotimes` instead. It is more readable, less confusing, and in general less prone to mistake.

With that in mind, your main function can be rewritten as:

```
(defun cand-set-count (m-dash set-count selected curr)
  (when (>= curr m)
    (incf set-count)
    (return-from cand-set-count 0))
  (dotimes (i n)
    (when (and (equal (aref m-dash curr i) 1)
               (null (aref selected i)))
        (setf (aref selected i) 1)
        (cand-set-count m-dash set-count selected (+ curr 1))
        (setf (aref selected i) nil))))
```

which is definitely clearer.

And now, the actual problem: the line `(incf set-count)` does *not* do what you think it does. It does *not* increase the value of the special variable named set-count ... and that would be clear, had you followed the convention of naming special variables with * around their name (I am not being sarcastic here: it is (one of ...) the reason conventions exist). What gets incremented is the *local* binding, not the value of the special variable. You can try it with a simpler code:

```
* (defvar *foo* 0)
0

* (defun bar (foo)
    (incf foo))
BAR

* (bar *foo*)
1

* *foo*
0
```

Said differently: you have a special (and so, in some sense, global) variable named `set-count`, but your function also takes an argument, named `set-count` ! Do you want to go pure functional & side-effect-free, or do you want to mutate state and pass global references around ? Either is fine, but you need to stick to it.

The same is true for the other arguments, `m-dash` and `selected`, that are both "shadowed" inside the function body, and never actually modified.

Another mistake that might bite you later on: arrays are not initialized by default. You cannot suppose that `(defvar selected (make-array n))` initializes anything to 0 or to `nil`; your function later tests if `(null (aref selected i))`, but if you do not explicitly initialize `selected` with `:initial-contents/:initial-element`, the result is undefined.